# Why crash reports from the iTunes Connect are so not informative?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, crash-reports

I've took the following crash report from the iTunes Connect:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0

0   CoreFoundation                     0x3226629e __exceptionPreprocess + 158
1   libobjc.A.dylib                    0x39f0097a objc_exception_throw + 26
2   CoreFoundation                     0x321b08d4 -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] + 764
3   *** MYAPP ***                      0x0001d994 0x00011000 + 51604
4   *** MYAPP ***                      0x0001cfb6 0x00011000 + 49078
```

How to build the application with debug symbols that iTunes Connect will symbolicate automatically?

Comment: The stack never went through any of your methods. But it's a sigabrt, seems to be a nil object is being added to an array.

Comment: If you add the objective C break point, it might break point at where the error is occurring.

Comment: Nil object can be added to the array. No breakpoints can be added to remote users of the application.

Comment: It's an NSArray ? or a CRefArray ?

Comment: I really don't know. I only have this crash report with just numbers. But I think it is `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: No, you can't add nil objects to an array. This will lead to an exception. My guess is that whatever you add there is nil.

Comment: Sorry, I mean code like this: `products = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: nil];`

Comment: Is the following code allowed: `[controllers addObject:[NSNull null]];`?

Comment: no that is not allowed

Comment: Are you sure about that? I think `NSNUll null` is not nil.

Comment: easier to wrap a test for the object being nil around the call to add to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert but...
To see methods in a crash report your machine needs to have a table of symbols from the app.
Did you build the app in Xcode on your Mac?
I believe there's a DSYM (debugger symbols) file generated when you build that holds a table of the symbols so that you can open a crash report in the Xcode > Organiser and see the addresses symbolicated to objects to get a better sense of what is happening.
This is all off the top of my head so [citation needed] but the short version is you need the symbol files. If you didn't build the app on your Mac then that;s why you're missing object names.

Heres a [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1747/_index.html) to Debugging Deployed iOS apps guide.
And one to the [parent](https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/debugging/) with all the debug info

Comment: How to build the application with debug symbols that iTunes Connect will symbolicate automatically?

Comment: By the way the application is always build on the Mac and I have all versions on the Organizer. But I can't see symbolicated crash reports on the xCode.

Comment: then I would definitely say read the debugging guides I linked to, they contain better info than I can give from my memory :)